# How do I copy the debug window contents including timestamps?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just installed Productivity Power Tools for VS2013. Now each line in the Debug Output window is prepended by a timestamp:

[image]

I'd like to save the window contents to file, but if I select all the text in the window and copy it to a new window, I only get the *text* of the messages - the copy contains no timestamp info.

How can I copy the window contents and get the timestamps too?